# Spring Boot disable creation of JpaProperties configuration in WAR deployment

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to setup a Spring Boot application that uses EclipseLink instead of Hibernate. The project has a similar structure to this example project:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/blob/master/jpa/eclipselink/src/main/java/example/springdata/jpa/eclipselink/Application.java

The main difference is that our application needs to be packaged as a WAR... so the main Application.java extends `SpringBootServletInitializer` instead of the `JpaBaseConfiguration` shown in the example (we have another bean with `@Configuration` that extends `JpaBaseConfiguration`).

When the app starts it encounters a ClassNotFoundException for the a naming strategy that comes form Hibernate:

```
Error creating bean with name 'spring.jpa-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/boot/model/naming/ImplicitNamingStrategy
```

It seems that this only happens when the application extends from SpringBootServletInitializer.

Turning on debug shows this:

```
JpaBaseConfiguration.JpaWebConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.jpa.open-in-view=true) found different value in property 'open-in-view' (OnPropertyCondition)
      Matched:
         - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer'; @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class (OnClassCondition)
         - found ConfigurableWebEnvironment (OnWebApplicationCondition)
```

Is there any way to exclude the `JpaWebConfiguration`, but still have the application extend from `SpringBootServletInitializer`?

UPDATE: After debugging this further I don't believe the JpaWebConfiguration is the issue as that is in the unmatched section of the debug, but something is still causing the creation of a JpaProperties bean and hitting the ClassNotFoundException.